# Gulp is not compiling SCSS to CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, gulp

I am new to gulp sass so I am currently learning with this https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/. The current topic I am working from the above link is **#Preprocessing with Gulp**

All the stuff is getting fine until I test my sass file after testing it ( to know that it is compiling the CSS )  I trigger that it is not compiling SCSS to CSS why is it so.

**Thinks to know.**

1. I am currently not working on my localhost. I have made the project file on my desktop.
2. I have created the CSS file manually for the first time to see that my SCSS compiles  my Current CSS file

What I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE :**

**Inside my Gulp file :**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task( 'sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
})
```

**My file structure:**

```
|- app/
      |- css/
      |- fonts/
      |- images/ 
      |- index.html
      |- js/ 
      |- scss/
           |- style.scss
|- dist/
|- gulpfile.js
|- node_modules/
|- package.json
```

***Note: The file Structure is same as in the CSS Trick.***

Comment: show us your gulpfile and file structure

Comment: @magreenberg Let me update.

Comment: @magreenberg I have updated my answer with my file structure and grunt file code

Comment: Do you have any folders in scss? The glob `app/scss/**/*.scss` is only going to see files with a `.scss` extension inside a subfolder.

Comment: do you get any errors when you run the sass task?

Comment: @lukeocom I don't get any type of error but can u tell me where should get the errors on the git console or on my web page

Comment: change your glob to app/scss/*.scss

Comment: @OwaizYusufi Maybe try changing line 6 to `.pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))` because if there is an error parsing your sass by default it will just kill the gulp process, with this option it'll actually log it out.

Comment: try changing paths like so "./app/scss/**/*.scss" and "./app/css"

Comment: Can U guys tell me that if the file trigger an error so where can I see it on my web page or in my console

Comment: The css file will automatically be created or not or I have to create it manually

Comment: @OwaizYusufi All CSS files should be created automatically, and all errors will show up in the console.

Comment: @Minzkraut Here it is the css file is not generating automatically and no errors in the console

Comment: Guys now when I am running the gulp it trigger an error at line 7 says that `.pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')); `

Comment: @OwaizYusufi Says what? your comment seems incomplete!

Comment: @Minzkraut https://imgur.com/9Xos0HX here is what it say

Comment: @OwaizYusufi just guessing, but are you missing a ';' on line 6?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155884/discussion-between-owaiz-yusufi-and-minzkraut).

Comment: remove the semicolon from - .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `./` to your source path:

```
return gulp.src('./app/scss/**/*.scss')
...
```

This tells it to start from the current directory, relative to the gulpfile.

Edit - you'll also need the same thing for the destination path:

```
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your gulpfile looks ok. Your folder structure is ok.

I would like to ask wether you installed gulp-sass in your machine.

If you have not install.

Install it `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`.

You don't need actually to create css file to test wether it works or not. It's ok if you have created too.

Check and let us know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the semicolon on this line

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
```

and add one o the end of the task, like this

```
gulp.task( 'sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});
```